# Is there a way to update the colours of annotations in Tableau based on data?

Tags: tableau-api

I am working in Tableau and want to format the colour of annotations in my visualisation based on data. For example, all the annotations (labels) for data points representing Australia need to be coloured blue and all data points representing NZ need to be yellow etc. Does anyone know a way that this can be automated??

Comment: Can you share a data set and workbook? One way to try is using a dual axis where one of the mark types is text.